# Why does some nodeJS tasks makes Ubuntu freeze and not Windows?

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, memory-management, process

I have been facing an intriguing problem lastly.

I am working on a project with a pretty heavy front in Angular JS with a hundred of Jest tests. I have 16 Go of ram but the project is so heavy that sometimes it fills up completely the ram and often the computer cannot handle the project running plus a `yarn test` at the same time (which takes up to 3 to 4 Go of ram) or a cypress workflow test without big latency problems.

To avoid big freezes (up to several minutes) and crashes, I increased the swap to 16 Go.

That being said, for various reasons I had to work on the project on Windows 10 and faced none of these problems.
Everything runs smoothly, the graphical interface doesn't lag even with screen sharing even-though the ram is also completely filled up and the CPU at 100%.

I am even able to run 20 `yarn test` at the same time without much lag which seems completely impossible on Linux even with the increased swap.

I've seen that windows use ram compression by default and not linux but I only had up to 549 Mo of compressed ram during my comparisons.
I firstly though that it could be a problem with gnome which is known to be heavy and sometimes buggy but I also tested it with KDE and have the same results.
I also heard that windows allocate special resources to the graphical environment where linux may treat it like any other process but that alone cannot explain all the problems because the whole computer freezes on linux and not in windows.

So I'm starting to wonder if there is something about the memory or process management that windows do significantly better than linux.

My config :

```
Computer model : Dell XPS-15-7590
Processor :      Intel core i7 9750H, 2,6 GHz, 4,5 GHz turbo max (6 cores, 12 threads)
RAM :            16 Go 
Graphic card :   GTX 1650M
Screen :         4K 16:9
SSD :            NVME 512 Go
```

Comment: What are "Mo" & "Go" units?

Comment: @Marc French for MB & GB

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 with 16GB RAM and Intel i5-12400 Processor

My solution was to limit the number of max workers on jest config

```
"maxWorkers": 4
```

Comment: Works for me too. You can also remove it from the jest config and use the `-w, --maxWorkers` command line argument: `npx jest -w 4`, `npx jest --maxWorkers 50%`, etc